# Broken Encryption on StackExchange?

Tags: support

I've been getting intermittent "Broken Encryption" messages on AskUbuntu's website. So far, I've only seen this on www.askubuntu.com and www.blender.stackexchange.com, and it's not always there.

Is this a problem with StackExchange, or is it a problem on my end?

[image: Broken Encryption]

Edit: To make the problem even more confusing, the error disappeared after I reloaded the website.

Comment: It says the encryption used AES 128 GCM, which, [according to CloudFlare at least](https://blog.cloudflare.com/staying-on-top-of-tls-attacks/) is pretty strong - and rather modern (TLS 1.2 only). Are you behind a company proxy or something?

Comment: I'm just connected to my home Wi-Fi network with no proxy or VPNs or anything like that. I've been using the same settings for almost 2 years, and I've never seen anything like this. I'll keep my eye on it to see if it happens on any other websites.

Comment: Related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272407/270345, perhaps?

Comment: Not quite. Firefox does have a warning, but I can still access the website. The message is in the same area as the mixed content blocker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out! I manually configured Firefox to block all mixed content. (by default, only active content is blocked) When I allow mixed display content (images) it gives me the mixed content message. When I block mixed display content, it gives me the weak encryption message.

In other words, it's a mixed content problem, which is server-side. Sorry for the stupid question, I guess I'm a little paranoid.

Comment: Fine fine we let you get away with it this time but do not dare to start asking questions about rootkits and virusscanners for linux :+)

Comment: @Rinzwind, I only asked this question here, because currently I'm only seeing this message on StackExchange websites.  ;)